# What are the cons and pros between SparkR and Revolution R?

Tags: r, distributed-computing

There are 2 ways to run the R parallelly, which are SparkR and RevolutionR.

From the compatibility with R,distribution processing effect, scalability, application scenarios, community support and maybe some other aspects, what are the real difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I known, the biggest difference is that Revolution R is a commercial software while SparkR is free. So, you even can't try most of the parallel functions of Revolution R before paid.

Wait for other guys w/ real experience of Revolution R to update the answer :)

Btw, there are not only 2 ways to run R parallel. Other approaches, such as `snow`, `multicore`, `parallel`, `Rmpi`, ... And offload to GPU as [here](http://www.parallelr.com/tranining/).

---

Check out below two links:

[RevolutionR](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/get-revolution-r)

[SparkR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very helpful to me, especially  the other approaches you mentioned above.@Patric